# How to perform a Hyperparameter tuning on yolo-nas model

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, yolo, training-data, hyperparameters

I have trained the yolo-Nas model with yolo_m, looking for a method to do hypermeter tuning for yolo_s and yolo_l.

Not only size of the model, are they any other method to choose batch size.

Are they any other parameters to train and if they are what are there and how to train with those parameters?